# Change font header with multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, latex

I would like to change the font type to the LaTeX font. So far managed to change the font in each individual plot. Unfortunately If I combine the two I can not change the "Main heading". Do you have any suggestions how to solve this? Appreciate!
(This is my very first question on stack overflow. I hope it is reproducible)

```
library(gridExtra)
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2)


df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 5:14, c = 2:11, d = 3:12)

font.set <- "LM Roman 10"

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(text=element_text(family = font.set)) +
  ggtitle("Plot 1")

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = c, y = d)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(text=element_text(family = font.set)) +
  ggtitle("Plot 2")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, top = "Main heading")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, 
         top = textGrob("Main heading", gp = gpar(fontfamily = font.set)))
```